# Ruby on rails: Arel tables join returns wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, jsonapi-resources

In ruby on rails when joining the two arel tables throws error "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0). Below is the sample

`tab_a = TableA.arel_table, tab_b = TableB.arel_table`

`query = tab_a[:column1].eq(tab_b[:column2]).and(tab_b[:column3].eq('test'))`

`TableA.all.where(tab_a.join(tab_b).on(query)).order(tab_b [:column4].send('asc'))`

this throws error "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you please tell on which line you are getting this error ? and also this query seems pretty straight why don't achieve same with **Active Record** ORM instead of **arel**

Comment: did you ever work this out?